# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'height' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'height' referenced before assignment.
i try to add variable as globally but that's not working can anyone please help me with this... Thanks in adavance.

THIS IS MY PYTHON CODE:

thermalscreening.py

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should review [ask]. screenshots of source code are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Seems on line 84 you have a while loop and on line 88 you have a break statement. That exits the while before height is assigned on line 92. However you're using the height variable on line 105.

Please also learn how to debug your python code to track down these issues without the need for stackoverflow.

Comment: height=0 
    width=0         i got the output i need to add this to line 84

Comment: Well looking at the code you might not want to do anything if you cant get ret and frame.